# How to merge DataFrames based on Datetime in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, python-datetime

I have written the following code which creates two dataframes `nq` and `cmnt`.
`nq` contains the `UserId` and corresponding time of Badge Attainment `date`.
`cmnt` contains `OwnerUserId` and the time when the User made a comment `CreationDate`.
I want to get a count of the comments made for all days before and after 1 week of badge attainment for every user and store it in a dataframe as shown.

The following code performs the same but produces an error for a part of the data whereas it works fine for the other part of the data. Please provide me an alternate way to do this task.

**nq**

```
 UserId |   date 
     1      2009-10-17 17:38:32.590
     2      2009-10-19 00:37:23.067
     3      2009-10-20 08:37:14.143
     4      2009-10-21 18:07:51.247
     5      2009-10-22 21:25:24.483
```

**cmnt**

```
OwnerUserId | CreationDate
1             2009-10-16 17:38:32.590
1             2009-10-18 17:38:32.590
2             2009-10-18 00:37:23.067
2             2009-10-17 00:37:23.067
2             2009-10-20 00:37:23.067
3             2009-10-19 08:37:14.143
4             2009-10-20 18:07:51.247
5             2009-10-21 21:25:24.483
```

**CODE**

```
t = pd.merge(nq, cmnt, left_on="UserId", right_on = "OwnerUserId")
t["days_diff"] = (t["CreationDate"] - t["date"]).dt.days
t["count"] = t.groupby(["UserId", "days_diff"]).OwnerUserId.transform("count")

all_days = pd.DataFrame(itertools.product(t.UserId.unique(), range(-7, 8)), )
all_days.columns = ["UserId", "day"]

t = pd.merge(t, all_days, left_on=["UserId", "days_diff"], right_on=["UserId", "day"], how = "right")
t = pd.pivot_table(t, index="UserId", columns="day", values="count", dropna=False)

res = pd.merge(nq, t, left_on="UserId", right_index=True)

print(res)
```

**Expected Output**

```
UserId     |   date                 |-7|-6|-5|-4|-3|-2|-1|0 |1 |2 |3 |4 |5 |6 |7
     1      2009-10-17 17:38:32.590 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |1 |0 |1 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0  
     2      2009-10-19 00:37:23.067 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |1 |1 |0 |1 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0    
     3      2009-10-20 08:37:14.143 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |1 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 
     4      2009-10-21 18:07:51.247 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |1 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 
     5      2009-10-22 21:25:24.483 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |1 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0
```

Here column `-1` means comment made 1 day before badge attainment and `1` means comment made one day after badge attainment and so on.

**ERROR**

```
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 0 elements, new values have 2 elements
```

**Note**
The error is caused at this line of code:
`all_days.columns = ["UserId", "day"]`

Comment: For the data you provided this works. Please provide an example where the error reproduces.

Comment: In your real dataframe, the length of the list to `all_days.columns` must be as long as there are columns. The error says `all_days` has no columns.

Comment: @ItaiS this code is a part of a function that performs a bit complicated task. Explaining it here will be difficult. If possible please provide an alternate code to do this.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney I understand that according to the error there are no columns but when I manually checked it at the time of error the columns were present in the form of `RangeIndex`. Can you please provide an alternate code to do this task?

Comment: That fine if it was a RangeIndex. This issue is, how many entries are there?

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney in the real dataset `nq` has 1500 instances and `cmnt` has 152581 instances. To obtain these 2 dataframes I have a function in which I pass a list of badges(about 30) for which I want the data. Now the error is for some (about 10) badges where this code does not work. The thing is the data is same for all badges and I don't have any reason for this error.